# How to divide values from a dictionary to an existing dataframe?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am struggling with adding data from a dictionary to a df. Different values from a dictionary need to be assigned to different rows in the df by Year.

I have tried to following:

```
bbp = {2010: 632, 2011: 658, 2012: 669, 2013: 671, 2014:679, 2015: 709, 2016: 728 ,2017: 748, 2018: 779 ,2019: 812, 2020: 770 }

aex['BBP'] = 0

for i in aex['Date']:
    for n in range(2010,2021):
         if str(n) in i:
            aex['BBP'] = bbp[n]
```

Result:
Only the value of bbp[2020] is placed for all rows in aex['BBP']

```
test = {'Date': ['7/11/2019', '7/12/2019','7/13/2019','7/14/2019'], 'BBP':[770, 770,770,770]}
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)
```

Could you please help dividing the dictionary properly over the column?
aex['Date'] is an object.

Comment: I'm quite confused on how is the original dict with the Dates and what is the final DF result you're expecting. Could you elaborate more on those examples? (as in, what is the `aex dict`?

Comment: Your code gives an error. Please [create a minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry ofc, I see what you mean. With test{}, I wanted to illustrate what result I am getting now. Unfortunately I can copy a picture. For all the rows of a specific year I want to insert the value of the Dictionary from that year. For example, where test['Date'] = 7/11/2010, I want value 632 in test['BBP']. Does this makes it clear?

Comment: I think so and I believe i know what you have to do, gimme some minutes and i'll reply

Comment: @J.Bravo added my answer, see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=bbp.keys(), data=bbp.values())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I need to add the values in an existing dataframe with df['Date'] columns containing the dates from 2010-2020. So I cant use the keys() as index.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you ?

You can traverse the `Date` list and update contents of the corresponding elements in the `bbp` list by using the year in the date as the key in the bbp dictionary.

```
bbp = {2010: 632, 2011: 658, 2012: 669, 2013: 671, 2014:679, 2015: 709, 2016: 728 ,2017: 748, 2018: 779 ,2019: 812, 2020: 770 }
test = {'Date': ['7/11/2019', '7/12/2019','7/13/2019','7/14/2019']}
test['BBP'] = [0] * len(test['Date'])

for i in range(len(test['Date'])):
    year = int(test['Date'][i].split('/')[2])
    test['BBP'][i] = bbp[year]
```

**Output :**

```
test

{'Date': ['7/11/2019', '7/12/2019', '7/13/2019', '7/14/2019'],
 'BBP': [812, 812, 812, 812]}
```

Comment: Happy it helped you. You can consider accepting the most suitable answer

Answer (score 0):

The code block bellow is split into 2, first half is making your example (for other people that lands here) and the second half the solution

```
import pandas as pd

# make your dict and df for examples
bbp = {2010: 632, 2011: 658, 2012: 669, 2013: 671, 2014:679, 2015: 709,
       2016: 728 ,2017: 748, 2018: 779 ,2019: 812, 2020: 770 }

# Changed some values do match the year of your BPP
test = {'Date': ['7/11/2017', '7/12/2018','7/13/2019','7/20/2020']}
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)   


# Converting to datetime so we can extract the year 
# (and also so it doesn't mix up other date formats as day-month-year)
test_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(test_df['Date'], format="%m/%d/%Y")
test_df['Date_year'] = test_df['Date'].dt.year

# Use pandas map to get the BPP values from the dict
test_df['bbp'] = test_df['Date_year'].map(bbp)

print(test_df)

#        Date  Date_year  bbp
#0 2017-07-11       2017  748
#1 2018-07-12       2018  779
#2 2019-07-13       2019  812
#3 2020-07-20       2020  770
```